# PHP MySQL allow users to insert record X times a day

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have a php mysql cms where users logon to add/insert daily stock value. Currently users can add the stock value unlimited times.

How will the PHP code be if I want to restrict them to add XX times (quota) a day ? Lets say If I want company abc to add two times a day or company def three times a day.

Following is my table:

http://imageshack.us/a/img69/5440/vhwd.png

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: verify quota > 0, decrement quota... was this what you were looking for??

Comment: Count the rows returned by searching for `comid` and todays date?

Comment: in either case, you have to handle race conditions.

Comment: hi martin, quota will come from mysql quota field so do i have to write a query before setting variable. And is that mysqli code you have used? unfortunately iam using mysql not mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. When they attempt post a stock value do a `SELECT` query to see how many times they’ve posted that day.

```
<?php
// set quota as a variable so it can easily be changed
$quota = 1;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // look up 
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM tblstock
            WHERE comid = ? AND DATE(updated) = CURDATE()";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($comid));

    $row = $stmt->fetchObject();

    if (intval($row->count) < $quota) {
        // insert stock
    }
    else {
        // quota has been hit
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but wouldn't it return nothing? Since `updated` is in datetime format, not date... Maybe search for the ones that start with the `CURDATE()`?

Comment: It was written off the cuff, but I think MySQL may internally convert `datetime` values to a date value (i.e. 2013-07-10 00:00:00) if checking against `CURDATE()`. I may be wrong though. As I say, the above was written off the cuff and untested, but should point the OP in the right direction.

Comment: Nothing better than a quick test, [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f85a/1). It doesn't work...

Comment: Works if `updated` is wrapped in `DATE` function. Updated answer to reflect this.